# Direct SQL function access or using WCF services to talk to SQL functions -- for implementing Business Rule

Tags: sql, wcf

We have a team of Database programmers but did not had the Web programmers in the company.Thus outsourced a software development application to a third party.

The Database is at our end for that software application. We are responsible for the schema of that database. The software has many web screens which should satisfy a set of business rules whenever user performs an action on the screen.  We are thinking of building a set of SQL functions for this Business Rule implementation. We would expose a set of SQL function to web developers which would allow them to validate business rules and notify the user whether a particular can be done or not on the screen.

Recently I read about the WCF service. You can create a set of WCF services which the web developers would use in their code to validate business rules.

Should I have the web developers access the SQL functions directly or create WCF services for each business rule.  These WCF services eventually would call the SQL functions in their implementation .In this case which one is the better approach

1) Direct access to SQL functions  or

2) Create WCF service which would ultimately call the SQL functions

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using WCF to expose the functionalities as it is more scalable than every client accessing the database directly. You could use [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937697) to expose the CRUD functionalities along with your business rules performed there.

Comment: So I should have set of Web service functions(Business Rules) build using WCF .The software then references this in their code. What are views on a MVC layer architecture http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36847/Three-Layer-Architecture-in-C-NET

Comment: Yes expose your CRUD with business rules via web services and the client software should access the web services to perform any data access/modification. MVC is a presentation architecture and I am not sure what you want to achieve with it in this scenario. The link you referenced in your comment is not MVC although the concept it is trying to explain is same as what I suggested above (think of business layer exposed as web services).